# how to call the function in array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call the function

```
int Even( int a[][MAX_COLUMNS], int length, int width)
```

inside the `main` to print the output to the user.

After running the program, i got the following error

```
`int Even(int,int,int) connot convert argument 1 from int [3][2] to int
```

Here's the code, 
Thank you for taking the time to help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_ROWS 3
#define MAX_COLUMNS 2


using namespace std;

int  Even(int A, int length, int width);

int main(){


    int A[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS] = { { 3, 2 }, { 4, 5 }, { 2, 2 } };

    cout << "There are " << Even(A,MAX_ROWS,MAX_COLUMNS) << " even numbers in the matrix." << endl;
        cout << "Goodbye :-)" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}


int Even( int a[][MAX_COLUMNS], int length, int width){

    int sum = 0;
    int i; 
    int j; 

    for (i = 0; i < length, i++;){

        for (j = 0; j < width, j++;){

            if (a[i][j]  % 2 == 0){

                sum++;
            }
        }

    }

    return sum;

}
```

Comment: Your forward declaration is wrong: `int Even(int A, int length, int width);`. Why are you using `int A` there?

Comment: @MihaiTodor  can you please explain to me how to call the function ` int Even(int A, int length, int width)`  inside the main function

Comment: Your function is `int Even( int a[][MAX_COLUMNS], int length, int width)`, not `int Even(int A, int length, int width)`.

Comment: @YalaMedicalTransportIncUs your declaration is wrong: `int Even(int A, int length, int width);` Based on this declaration, `Even` gets three int parameters you should switch it to `int Even(int *A, int length, int width);`

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.  The syntax is a lot easier.  You also won't have to pass the number of elements in the array nor the array capacity.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I did the same thing as you said but i'm still  having the same error `int Even(int,int,int) cannot convert argument 1 from int [3][2] to int

Comment: I don't think you did it properly. Read your code carefully and then update your question with the latest version if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

You should alwais avoid forward declaration (except special cases).  At your Q it leaded you to error. Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_ROWS 3
#define MAX_COLUMNS 2

using namespace std;

int Even( int a[][MAX_COLUMNS], int length, int width){

    int sum = 0;
    int i; 
    int j; 

    for (i = 0; i < length, i++;){

        for (j = 0; j < width, j++;){

            if (a[i][j]  % 2 == 0){

                sum++;
            }
        }

    }

    return sum;

}

int main(){


    int A[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS] = { { 3, 2 }, { 4, 5 }, { 2, 2 } };

    cout << "There are " << Even(A,MAX_ROWS,MAX_COLUMNS) << " even numbers in the matrix." << endl;
    cout << "Goodbye :-)" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: *Why* should forward declaration(!) be avoided?! If you ask me, you *should* use it as a rule.

Comment: @Biffen Usually you don't need forward declaration except cases, when you need break circular depencency of classes. Other using of forward declaration (such as this case) only leads to terrible code, usually with mistakes.

Comment: I strongly disagree. In my view they help define interfaces, and can often help *avoid* errors. And header files tend to be full of forward declarations.

Comment: @Biffen Well, I dont speak about headers. That is sure that code divided to declaration and implementation helps to define good API (or interface). But this is not forward declaration (as I was taught). And you can see, that code in question does not have declaration and definition, only definition and before it forward declaration. And from my point of view this is not readable at all and generally it is bad.